# Insert from SQL to SQLBase with linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery, sqlbase

how can i insert from SQL Server to a SQLBase Database using linked Server?

Answer (score 0):

Here are various examples of the correct syntax for SQLServer to SQLBase assuming your LinkedServer is called 'ISLANDLINK' . **Note the two dots**.

or Go here for the full script and explanation :  [SQLServer to SQLBase via LinkedServer](https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/SqlBase#How_to_use_OLEDB_to_access_SQLBase_from_SQLServer)

or Go here for another example: [SQLServer to SQLBase via LinkedServer (more)](https://forum.tdcommunity.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=58&p=146&hilit=Linked#p146)

```html
--Select:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( ISLANDLINK, 'Select * from SYSADM.BUDGET where DEPT_ID = ''MIS'' ') 

--Update:
UPDATE [ISLANDLINK]..[SYSADM].[BUDGET]
   SET [BGT_YEAR] = 2016
WHERE DEPT_ID = 'MIS'

GO

--Insert:
INSERT INTO [ISLANDLINK]..[SYSADM].[EMPLOYEE]
           ([EMPLOYEE_ID]
           ,[LAST_NAME])     VALUES (99  ,'PLUMAS' )

GO

--Delete:
DELETE FROM [ISLANDLINK]..[SYSADM].[EMPLOYEE]
      WHERE [LAST_NAME] = 'PLUMAS'
```